# Transaction Log Shipping Removal, Backup and Drop Database

Tags: backup, transaction-log

I have  databases (about 15 different) Production Databases set for Log_Shipping and I would like to take a full backup of it and need to drop from production later on because we have already move it to new environment.

Should I, just end log shipping and back up database?
Should I, just take backup and keep log shipping on until I, drop it from current environment?
How should I remove log shipping from current environment at the time of drop of databases.

Thank You for help and time.

Comment: Care to mention what DBMS this is about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first remove logshipping using below procedure. You can use both TSQL and SSMS for this

To [Remove Log Shipping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189071.aspx)

On the log shipping primary server, execute [sp_delete_log_shipping_primary_secondary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189467.aspx) to delete the information about the secondary database from the primary server.

On the log shipping secondary server, execute [sp_delete_log_shipping_secondary_database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188928.aspx) to delete the secondary database.

> Note
>
> If there are no other secondary databases with the same secondary ID, sp_delete_log_shipping_secondary_primary is invoked from sp_delete_log_shipping_secondary_database and deletes the entry for the secondary ID and the copy and restore jobs.

On the log shipping primary server, execute sp_delete_log_shipping_primary_database to delete information about the log shipping configuration from the primary server. This also deletes the backup job.

On the log shipping primary server, disable the backup job.

On the log shipping secondary server, disable the copy and restore jobs.

Optionally, if you are no longer using the log shipping secondary database, you can delete it from the secondary server.

To remove Log Shipping using SSMS

Right-click the database you want to use as your primary database in the log shipping configuration, and then click Properties.

Under Select a page, click Transaction Log Shipping.

Clear the Enable this as a primary database in a log shipping configuration check box.

Click OK to remove log shipping from this primary database.

After logshipping is removed drop databases.